# How to get longitude and latitude in degree units

Tags: openlayers-2, latitude-longitude

When i navigate on my map , I receive the latitude and longitude, but I want them to be specified in degrees. I don't know what should I do please help 
this is my code:

```
        function toggleControl(element) {
            for(key in drawControls) {
                var control = drawControls[key];
                if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
                    control.activate();
                } else {
                    control.deactivate();
                }
            }
        }

        function allowPan(element) {
            var stop = !element.checked;
            for(var key in drawControls) {
                drawControls[key].handler.stopDown = stop;
                drawControls[key].handler.stopUp = stop;
            }
        }

         function handleMeasurements(event) {
        var geometry = event.geometry;
        var units = event.units;
        var order = event.order;
        var measure = event.measure;
        var element = document.getElementById('output');
        var out = "";
        if(order == 1) {
            out += "measure: " + measure.toFixed(3) + " " + units;
            //alert("measure " + measure.toFixed(3) + " " +
             //                   + units + " ");
        } else {
            out += "measure: " + measure.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "<sup>2</" + "sup>";
        }
        element.innerHTML = out;
    }

    function toggleControl(element) {
        for(key in measureControls) {
            var control = measureControls[key];
            if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
                control.activate();
            } else {
                control.deactivate();
            }
        }
    }

    function toggleGeodesic(element) {
        for(key in measureControls) {
            var control = measureControls[key];
            control.geodesic = element.checked;
        }
    }

    function toggleImmediate(element) {
        for(key in measureControls) {
            var control = measureControls[key];
            control.setImmediate(element.checked);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this function, provided by Openlayers:

[getFormmatedLonLat](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Util-js.html#Util.getFormattedLonLat) function, in the Openlayers.Utils object.

An use example:

```
var ns = OpenLayers.Util.getFormattedLonLat(point.lat, 'lat', 'dms');
var ew = OpenLayers.Util.getFormattedLonLat(point.lon, 'lon', 'dms');
```

The output must be a string like:

> Xº Y' Z''

for each coordinate.